# IIS HTTP to HTTPS web.config rewrite doesn't return entire URL

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, web-config

So I have been trying to rewrite using the following:

```
<rules>
  <rule name="HttpToHttps" stopProcessing="true"/>
    <match url="(.*)"/>
    <conditions>
      <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true"/>
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{URL}"/>
  </rule>
<rules>
```

In two environments, this redirects like it should.  In a third environment, it doesn't work.  It doesn't work in the sense of, looking at a fiddler log, I see the http call with the full url.  When it redirects to https, it removes everything after the HTTP_HOST.

So using the following url:

> nonsecure://www.mysite.com/page.aspx?var1=1&var2=2

In two environments, it becomes

> secure://www.mysite.com/page.aspx?var1=1&var2=2

In the third it becomes:

> secure://www.mysite.com

I tried rewriting it as https://{HTTP_HOST}{HTTP_URL} and that doubled the {URL} in the first two environments:

> secure://www.mysite.com/page.aspx?var1=1&var2=2&var1=1&var2=2

I'm not very experienced with web.configs, kinda learning as I go, so if anyone has any input as to what's going on here, it would be greatly appreciated.  If it has any bearing on anything, the third environment is on two servers that are load balanced.

Comment: nonsecure = http and secure = https - It was yelling at me about posting more than two links.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ruslany has several IIS URL Rewrite examples on his blog, HTTP to HTTPS is one of them:

```
<rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

See http://ruslany.net/2009/04/10-url-rewriting-tips-and-tricks/ for more.

Comment: This was some helpful information - however it still doesn't work.

Comment: @Nick Strange, then there might be other factors in play. The rule above works perfectly in my scenario:
    `GET http://ssl.example.com/?var1=1&var2=2&var3=aaa&var4=lkesr HTTP/1.1
    User-Agent: Fiddler
    Host: ssl.example.com

    HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
    Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
    Location: https://ssl.example.com/?var1=1&var2=2&var3=aaa&var4=lkesr
    Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0`

(I had to munge my test domain)

Comment: I would upvote this, however I need 15 reputation to do so :/.  The problem was that a load balancer had a url rewrite rule on it as well, which was munching the query part of the url, and then returning the base part.