# redirect http to https Infinity loop 301 IIS(load balancing environment)

Tags: asp.net, redirect, iis, url-rewriting

Here is the broken piece of the rewrite rules

```
    <rules>
                    <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
                        <match url="(.*)" />
                        <conditions>
                            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
                        </conditions>
                        <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com/TEST_SITE/{R:1}"
                                redirectType="Permanent" />
                    </rule>
    </rules>
```

My intention is to test if redirect http to https works on my test site, however,it will be a infinity loop with code 301 (Moved Permanently)

If I change the url="https://www.example.com/**TEST_SITE**/{R:1} to url="{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}", it will work, no more loop. But instead of redirecting me to https://www.example.com/TEST_SITE/, it redirects me to https://www.example.com/ (prod environment).

Any ideas to fix this ? Thanks

Comment: What happens if you change `url="https://www.example.com/TEST_SITE/{R:1}"` to `url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/TEST_SITE/{R:1}"`? There are more HTTP to HTTPS redirect examples on http://stackoverflow.com/a/14925644/1297898 and https://www.saotn.org/iis-url-rewrite-redirect-http-to-https/. Sometimes it takes some fiddling :)

Comment: @Jan Reilink  url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/TEST_SITE/{R:1}  I tried this one before, doesn't work . Thanks for your comments and links. I will look into it.

Comment: Where exactly is the rule defined ? At the example.com level or example.com/TEST_SITE level . See this blog https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaushal/2013/05/22/http-to-https-redirects-on-iis-7-x-and-higher/ it says - "NOTE: Ensure the rewrite rule is disabled at each of the virtual directories/applications under the Default Web Site. Due to inheritance, the rule will cause the requests to end up in infinite loop calling itself repeatedly.     "

Comment: I fixed this issue after a while. I printed out all the server variable , it turns out the server variable {https} returns nothing and it returns an additional variable {http-x-SSL} to indicate  if  its  SSL connections.  Thank you all

Comment: Great one @uonlyYOLOonce ! Perhaps you can update your question with your solution? My best guess is that there is an URL Rewrite active on the load balancer ("lb") and/or traffic from the lb to the webservers is not SSL encrypted.

Answer (score 0):

Stupid of me I didn't think of this yesterday... Add your domain name / HTTP_HOST as an input condition.

This comes from a real-life example from my site:

```
<!-- redirect HTTP naar HTTPS for WordPress https://www.saotn.org/ssl-wordpress-move-wordpress-site-https-definitive-guide/ -->
  <!-- see https://www.saotn.org/redirect-http-to-https-on-iis/ and
    https://www.saotn.org/iis-url-rewrite-redirect-http-to-https/ for more 
  information -->
  <rule name="example.com http to https" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
      <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www.)?example\.com$" />
      <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
      <add input="{URL}" pattern="(.*)" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
  </rule>
```

Your `TEST_SITE` should be in the `{URL}` input pattern, captured in `{R:1}`.

Comment: Still, redirects me to the www.example.com  instead of www.example.com/test_site. One thing I need to mention is that this is not a single server.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this out

```
<rule name="HTTP To HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="OFF" />
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(([^\.]+)\.)?example.com$" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:0}" />
    </rule>
```